# What heroes in the current DotA have been present since the old DotA versions? How have they changed?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Some sites and forums have mentioned old heroes in DotA, but they only mention those who were already removed from the game.

What heroes have existed way back when DotA was in the "Warcraft: Reign of Chaos" days or prior to the popularity of DotA "AllStars", that still exist now? How have they changed?

Comment: Won't add this as an answer, since it doesn't have enough detail, but: Basically all classic heroes that you could recruit during normal RTS play (non-dota) in Warcraft 3 are both in Dota Allstars and Dota 2 in one form or another, with slightly altered abilities.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=348720) a thread with a bunch of old versions of heroes. They've come a long way!